# What does mean "to be interested in someone"?

Tags: meaning

Example: She doesn't seem the least bit interested in him.
Does she interest him or is she of interest to him?

Comment: Interested in forming a romantic attachment?

Comment: @WS2 yes, or maybe sexual

Comment: I am so old that I belong to a generation that associates the two notions as one.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  (Actually, "she interests him" and "she is of interest to him" mean the same thing.)

She's not interested in him means that she's not interested by him, i.e., she finds that he's not worthy of her attention.

If she's not interesting to him, then the lack of regard runs the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If someone said "She doesn't seem the least bit interested in him" I would take that to mean that she does not find him attractive or appealing at all, for purposes of dating, or forming a friendship/romantic relationship.

Answer (score 0):

To *be interested in* someone or something means to *find* it *worthy of further attention*.
If "She doesn't seem the least bit interested in him" this indicates she doesn't desire to pay attention to him, for whatever purpose may be clear from context.
If she's a hiring manager and he's a job candidate, she doesn't plan to hire him.
If she's an admissions officer at a college and he's an applicant, he probably won't get in.
Without qualification, it might refer to personal interest, e.g. she's not interested in forming a personal relationship with him.

The sentence gives us no information about what he thinks of her.   For example, we don't know if he finds her warranting further attention or not.

---

Also for your information, we have a site for [English language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) that might be a good resource for some of your future questions.